# How do I install rEFInd themes?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, themes, refind

So, im pretty new to linux as I need to start using it next year in school.
I dual booted my laptop and I wanted a boot manager (not grub) so I could switch elegantly between Windows and Ubuntu. But I dont particularly like the standard theme of rEFInd. I want to install this theme. But when I follow the steps, some commands are not giving any feedback whatsoever. When I got to step 4 the terminal gives me:
Directory '/boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind-theme-regular' does not exist.
And when I get to the last step, I have no clue what to do.
Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include a link to those instructions, so we know what 'step 4' refers to.

Comment: @Niek Scholten  Do you mean "this theme" or just rEFInd themes in general?  In addition to providing a link to the instructions you are trying to use, as already suggested, giving specific details of the theme or package involved may allow others to provide you with a solution.

Comment: Im very sorry for my lack of response, but my hard drive crashed and I ended up sticking with grub anyway, thank you for your response!